# Any way to .. refuse my answer to be accepted (green-checkmarked)?

Tags: discussion

Concerned about this regarding my answer to [Can I save peanut oil from turkey fryer after rain?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85599/can-i-save-peanut-oil-from-turkey-fryer-after-rain).

It is not the best answer, since it describes no method to make the oil safe, just the fact that the oil as is might be very unsafe. Which I felt had to be urgently said.

Keeping this greenchecked will discourage more informative answers from people much more experienced in the subject matter than me.

Comment: That it's unsafe is an answer imo. That there's no way to do something, backed up is fine, and you can always improve an answer

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no you can't. You might consider bringing it up on SE meta, we're knocking it around the moderator room now.

Another mod commented that if you don't think your answer should be an answer, perhaps it stands to reason that it shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit it to the point where you think it is good enough to accept.

Or... you can delete it, if you really don't want it to ever rank highly as an answer.

If you don't want the information you provided *gone* and are looking for a middle ground, you can also suggest additions to a *different* answer that you think is otherwise good enough to accept but is missing something you had to say. Once that's done, deleting yours hopefully wouldn't be much of a loss.

For what it's worth, while we really don't want *answers* in comments, I think that short-term comments ("until someone writes a full answer, definitely don't try to heat it, it's dangerous") are usually fine.